# Dynamically display data from DB based on selection from checkbox in jsp

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp, servlets

**How to retrieve data in textbox by selecting option in check box?**

Full Requirement Description:

1) Select the multiple option in checkbox.
   For ex: Select Multiple names of checkbox.

2) Click the submit button.

2) In the next page data of other column should be displayed.
   For ex: All the Email-id should be displayed in textbox based on 'Names' selection in previous page

Requirement: Simple code Using JSP and Mysql

**

> Form1:
>
> ```
>    1)It contains Checkbox: User selects the check box and clicks on submit button. (Moves to next Form i.e Form2 - Check the next set of code below)
> ```

**

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<%-- 
    Document   : TestAllocMainPage
    Created on : Dec 7, 2015, 6:38:37 PM
    Author     : zanxzanz
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%ResultSet modelSet = null;%> 


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test Alloc</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <FORM method="POST" ACTION="NextForm.jsp">

           <%
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection connection
                        = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_management", "root", "admin");


                Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();
                modelSet = statement1.executeQuery("select * from manage_model");
                %>


<center>
Select(s): <br><br>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Select Model:</td>
    <td><select name="model" id="tb1"> 
                        <%
                        while (modelSet.next()) {%> 
                        <option><%=modelSet.getString(3)%></option> 
                        <% } %> 
                    </select></td>

</table>
<br><br>
<table
<tr>   

    <td> 
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=member value =Name1>
    </td>    
    <td>    
        Tester1 
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> 
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=member VALUE=Name2>
    </td>    
    <td>    
        Tester2
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> 
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=member VALUE=Name3>
    </td>    

    <td>    
        Tester3
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> 
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=member VALUE=Name4>
    </td>    

    <td>    
        Tester4
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> 
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=member VALUE=Name5>
    </td>    

    <td>    
        Tester5
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br> <INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit Value="Submit">
</center>
                    <%
        //**Should I input the codes here?** 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("wrong entry" + e);
            }
        %> 

</FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

**

> Form2:
>
> ```
>    1)Selected Names(checkbox) will be displayed in textbox
>    2)In 'mail' textbox email-id should be retrieved from mysql based on the 'Names' selected.
> ```

**

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<%-- 
    Document   : TestAllocProceedMain
    Created on : Dec 15, 2015, 10:37:04 AM
    Author     : zanxzanz
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%ResultSet mailSet = null;%> 

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>TAP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%! String[] members; %>
        <%! String models; %>
        <%! String mail; %>
    <center>Allocation Details: <br>

        <%

            String a = request.getParameter("member1");

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection connection
                        = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_management", "root", "admin");
                Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();

                mailSet = statement1.executeQuery("select Email_Id from team_member where Emp_Name ='Name1'");

                %>
        <table>
<% 
   members = request.getParameterValues("member");
   models = request.getParameter("model");


   if (members != null) 
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < members.length; i++) 
      {
         //out.println ("<b> Tester"+i+ ": <b>");
         %>
         <input type="text" name="test" value="<%=models%>" />
         <input type="text" name="test" value="<%=members[i]%>"/>
    //**Email**
    <input type="text" name="mail" value="<%=mail%>" />
         <br><br>
    <%
      }

   }
   else out.println ("<b>none<b>");
%>
</td></tr>
</table>

<%

            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("wrong entry" + e);
            }
        %> 

</center>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi rahat, <br/> My requirement is as follows: <br/> JspPage 1: There are list of checkbox for selection: for ex: Employee names list in checkbox. <br/> User selects the multiple option and clicks on submit button. <br/> In the next page Names and email-id of select employee is displayed. <br/> Please help me out.

Comment: Edit your question and put your codes in question. This way people can help you. We won't gonna write the full code from scratch.

Comment: smartrahat, Please help! I am new to jsp.